# Dell XPS 9320 occasional freezing in Ubuntu 22.04 (GPU HANG: ecode 12:0:00000000)

Tags: drivers, kernel, dell, freeze, xps

I've installed a stock minimal install of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I get occasional freezes where the display locks up for about 15-30 seconds and then resumes. All inputs through keyboard and mouse are still sent through and audio continues to play indicating the system is still responsive despite the display freeze.

Looking through journalctl indicates a GPU HANG from the i915 driver with error code 12:0:00000000

```
Sep 08 16:39:52 XPS-9320 kernel: Asynchronous wait on fence 0000:00:02.0:gnome-shell[2057]:5c814 timed out (hint:intel_atomic_commit_ready [i915])
Sep 08 16:39:56 XPS-9320 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:0:00000000
Sep 08 16:39:56 XPS-9320 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
Sep 08 16:39:56 XPS-9320 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_62.0.3.bin version 62.0 submission:enabled
Sep 08 16:39:56 XPS-9320 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC SLPC: enabled
Sep 08 16:39:56 XPS-9320 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9 authenticated:yes
```

This issue persists on clean re-installs Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on a ThinkPad X1 Carbon 10th gen, it has the same Alder Lake iGPU and it happens also on Arch with 'bleeding edge everything'. Kernel `5.19.8-arch1-1`, `GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.1.1.bin version 70.1`, `HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9`.

Comment: I have this issue as well on an ASUS laptop, without solution so far. It seems to be tracked here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/6916